# how to get relations family

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have these tables

person table with following data

```
person_id    description

1          first in the family
2          SON OF PERSON 1
3          SON OF PEROSN 2
4          SON OF PEROSN 3
5          SON OF PERSON 4
6          SON OF  PERSON 2
7          SON OF  PERSON 3
8          SON OF PERSON 3
9          SON OF PERSON 7
```

person_name table with following data

```
person_id  first_name

1        Santiago
2         Lautaro
3          Lucas
4          Franco
5          Agustín
6          MOLE
7          BULLY
8          CIVAL
9          NUMA
```

father table with following data

```
person_father_id  description
1              father of Lautaro
2              father of Lucas
3              father of Franco
4              father of Agustín
7              FATHER OF NUMA
```

children table with following data

```
 person_child_id   person_father_id
  2                 1
  3                 2
  4                 3
  5                 4
  6                 2
  7                 3
  8                 3
  9                 7
```

HOW TO GET RELATIONS BETWEEN FAMILY FOR EXAMPLE THE UNCLE OF PERSON NUMBER 4.
AND THE NEPHEW OF PERSON NUMBER 2 AND THE GRAND FATHER OF PERSON 4

Comment: This sounds like homework.  Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: It also sounds quite similar to your previous questions. Please edit your question to show what you have tried to do to solve this task, and what was wrong with it (errors, wrong results), and explain how you decide and identify what your starting point is (which person number) and the relation(s) you are looking for.

Comment: @AlexPoole you are right, the same tables but I need relations .

Comment: and person number means PERSON ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2a0bc/23)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE number_table AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE TABLE relationships (child_id, father_id ) AS
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 7 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT n.COLUMN_VALUE ||' IS THE NEPHEW OF ' || u.COLUMN_VALUE AS nephew
FROM   (
         SELECT children AS nephews,
                PRIOR CHILDREN MULTISET EXCEPT NUMBER_TABLE( father_id ) AS uncles
         FROM   (
           SELECT father_id,
                  CAST( COLLECT( child_id ORDER BY child_id ) AS number_table ) AS children
           FROM   relationships
           GROUP BY father_id
         )
         WHERE LEVEL = 2
         CONNECT BY father_id MEMBER OF PRIOR children
       ) t
       CROSS JOIN TABLE( t.nephews ) n
       CROSS JOIN TABLE( t.uncles ) u
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2a0bc/23/0)**:

```
|               NEPHEW |
|----------------------|
| 4 IS THE NEPHEW OF 6 |
| 7 IS THE NEPHEW OF 6 |
| 8 IS THE NEPHEW OF 6 |
| 5 IS THE NEPHEW OF 7 |
| 5 IS THE NEPHEW OF 8 |
| 9 IS THE NEPHEW OF 4 |
| 9 IS THE NEPHEW OF 8 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT PRIOR father_id || ' IS THE GRANDFATHER OF ' || child_id AS grandfather
FROM   relationships
WHERE  LEVEL = 2
CONNECT BY father_id = PRIOR child_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2a0bc/23/1)**:

```
|               GRANDFATHER |
|---------------------------|
| 1 IS THE GRANDFATHER OF 3 |
| 1 IS THE GRANDFATHER OF 6 |
| 2 IS THE GRANDFATHER OF 4 |
| 2 IS THE GRANDFATHER OF 8 |
| 2 IS THE GRANDFATHER OF 7 |
| 3 IS THE GRANDFATHER OF 5 |
| 3 IS THE GRANDFATHER OF 9 |
```

Comment: why you creat type

Comment: @JASA I am assuming that you can generate the uncles from the nephews relationship. The type is created to hold the collection of siblings needed to generate the uncle-nephew relationship.

Comment: @JASA There is no new table in my queries.

Comment: and what you call this CREATE TABLE relationships (child_id, father_id )

Comment: could find cousins?

Comment: @JASA It is the children table that you have in your question! There is no new tables - just the table you had in the question.